# Nested if with openxlpy

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, openpyxl

```
for status in sheet['E']:
   if status.value == 'completed':
      for price in sheet['G']:
         print(price.value)
```

It seems that if statement is not working because all of the price.value's are getting printed. What am I missing?

```
E
---------
completed
cart
None
completed
processing
completed

G
----------
120
30

300
50
450
```

I want to print the prices which their status is completed.so the expected outcome is :

```
120, 300, 450
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information, so we can't help You. Please edit your question and provide input data as well as expected output.

Comment: @fejs I have added more info. Thanks

Comment: Why is the loop nested? `cell.offset()` is probably all your need but your question is too vague to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/workbook.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
for i in range(1, 10): # You can use 32767 to get all rows
    if ws.cell(row=i, column=5).value == "completed": # column 5 is column E
        print(ws.cell(row=i, column=7).value) # column 7 is column G
```

**EDIT**

Seems that `openpyxl` uses 1-based indexing, rather than 0-based. So, adjust values accordingly.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `ValueError: Row or column values must be at least 1`

Comment: openpyxl provides methods for looping through rows and columns so you don't have to worry that much about indexing.

Comment: I agree, but I think it would over-complicate the solution.

Comment: @Fejs the edited version is working thanks. Why my code is not working?

Comment: In short, You're not matching rows. In case You get "completed" value, You go through ALL the cells.

Comment: Fejs, using either `cell.offset()` or ws['E:G]` would be the least complicated approach.